# What properties on Department domain entity for CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm trying out in CQRS for the first time and need some advice.

In my business, a department can be renamed. To do this, I dispatch a RenameDepartment command, caught by a command handler. This handler will then invoke the rename method on the Department entity, should this do anything to do the entity i.e update a name property?? As the name is purely for View purposes only, all i guess i should do is dispatch a DepartmentRenamed event and update the appropriate ViewModels, is this correct in my thinking?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQRS is where the responsibility for reads, and responsibility for writes, are split in to separate parts:

1. Write Store, event store to persist all of the events that happen in your domain
2. Read store, to persist the projections that are built incrementally from the stream of events coming from the write model's event store.

You have got it correct, in that your `RenameDepartmentCommandHandler` would handle the command `RenameDepartmentCommand`:

```
public void RenameDepartmentCommandHandler(RenameDepartmentCommand command)
{
    // repository is injected in for us during command handler instantiation
    var dept = this.repository.GetByDeptName(command.DepartmentName);
    dept.RenameDepartment(command.NewDepartmentName);
    this.repository.Save(dept);

    // the repository will save all of the events, once committed
    // a separate piece of code running in the background will
    // listen for new events from the the event-store and dispatch
    // them to anyone who may be listening
}
```

The actual entity would need to be updated in the write model by persisting the event, this is your single source of truth. You wouldn't only update the read model, you always update the write model.

After the write model has persisted the event, it would then be dispatched (at some point of time in the future) to the read model.

The read model is a slave from the write model. Because it is a slave, it will be eventually consistent (for read and write models which use separate infrastructure and that do not use distributed transactions)... eventually consistent doesn't mean a problem, typically a delay (10ms to second or even minutes) is acceptable to most problem spaces.

So your entity would look like this:

```
public class Department : AggregateBase
{
    // this class derives from jOliver's CommonDomain project
    // only useful if using C# - there will be similar
    // event sourcing infrastructure projects for different
    // languages

    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    // all other properties go here

    public void RenameDepartment(public newName)
    {
        // the DepartmentRenamed is an immutable class taking the
        // current name and new name as constructor parameters          
        RaiseEvent(new DepartmentRenamed(this.Name, newName));
    }

    protected void Apply(DepartmentRenamed evnt)
    {
        this.Name = event.NewName;
    }
}
```

And your read model projection something like this:

```
public class DeptNameListProjection : IEventHandler<DepartmentRenamed>
{
    public void Handle(DepartmentRenamed evntFromEventStore)
    {
        var department = this.readStore.Find(evntFromEventStore.OldName);
        // write it, depends on your infrastructure
        // normally a SqlCommand or similar is fine here, I try and avoid
        // using an ORM as imho flat tables make more sense for read models
    }
}
```